# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long - executemany sql insert

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, odbc

I'm trying to INSERT a pandas dataframe/table into a SQL Server database with ceODBC. 
I create a list of tuples from the dataframe first and then use the executemany() method which executes the INSERT command for every tuple in the list.

```
data = [ tuple(x) for x in table.values ]
cursor.executemany( SQLCommand, data )
```

The Sql command looks something like this but with lots more variables --

```
 "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
```

I'm getting a Python OverflowError. 
There are values in the dataframe that are greater than 2^31-1, the largest positive integer a C long type can store.

```
>>> junecps.max().max() > 2**31-1
True
```

But I am using a 64-bit machine with 64-bit python 3.4 so I'm confused as to why I'm triggering this error. None of the values in my dataframe are above this sys.maxsize.

```
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> junecps.max().max() > 2**63-1
False
```

Here's the traceback.

```
Writing SQL 'Insert' Command
INSERTing 1494250 rows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-----", line 93, in <module>
    pysql.uploadTable( connection, junecps, 'CPSProcessedJune' )
  File "-----", line 131, in uploadTable
    cursor.executemany( SQLCommand, data )
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: Can you check to see which row fails? Update your code with the value for that tuple and run it using only a single sequence. Does it still fail?

Comment: There's a column (PersonID which is 11 digits e.g 20160000101) with values above 2*31-1. It works fine without this column